# Fetch data is empty in componentwillMount in react native redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Hello I'm trying to learn react native from Stephen Grider's react-native course.I'm stuck to load data from my webservice and list them by using redux and lodash .I can successfully get data and can see it in render (console.log) ,and  but my props always is null  in componentDidUpdate or componentWillMount .
 Any help is appreciated,thanks.
Reducer is like this;

```
    import { TEST_FETCH, TEST_LOAD } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = { dataSource: [] };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TEST_FETCH:
      return { ...state, loading: false, dataSource: action.payload.data };
    case TEST_LOAD:
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: "" };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and action is ;

```
    import { TEST_LOAD, TEST_FETCH } from "./types";
export  const  getdata = ( ) => {
  return  dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: TEST_LOAD });
     fetch("http://myserver/getdata", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        return responseData;
      })

      .then(data => {
        // return data;
        dispatch({ type: TEST_FETCH, payload: data });
      });
  };
};
```

and page is ;

```
       import _ from 'lodash';
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { View, Text, ListView } from "react-native";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { getdata } from "../actions";

    class testList extends Component {
      componentWillMount() {
       this.props.getdata();
      }
      componentDidMount() {
       console.log(this.props.myarray ); // myarray is empty
        this.createDataSource(this.props.myarray);
      }

      componentDidUpdate() {
       console.log(this.props.myarray ); // I tried this but still myarray is empty
        this.createDataSource(this.props.myarray);
      }
      createDataSource({ dtsource }) {
// sure dtsource is null too
         const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
         this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(dtsource);
      }
      render() {
    console.log(this.props.myarray); // if I write here,I can see my json's output
        return <View>
            <Text>Employee List</Text>
            <ListView dataSource={this.props.myarray} renderRow={rowData => <Text
                >
                  {rowData}
                </Text>} />
          </View>;
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      const myarray= _.map(state.testForm.dataSource, function(v) {
        return { ...v };
      });
          return { myarray};
    };
    export default connect(mapStateToProps , { getdata })(testList);
```

Comment: You should dispatch your action from componentDidMount. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount.

Comment: Where is `this.props.arr1` coming from?

Comment: @CarlosC sorry ,i forget to change it while writing here.It is myarray

Comment: You're passing `mapDispatchToProps` in to `connect()`. It should be `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I correct that, but I wrote this  wrong here.Sorry

Comment: @CarlosC IF you mean this ,i try know but still see  myarray ,its still empty. componentDidMount() {
       this.props.getdata();
      }

Comment: Your just passing an array to the dataSource which is not what expects. It expects a ListViewDataSource. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#datasource

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a FlatList since ListView is deprecated and has bad performance. In the meantime, you can use the code snippet below to pass the correct object to dataSource. You might need to add some `null` checks depending on the state of the data you pass to `myarray`.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, ListView } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getdata } from "../actions";

class testList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {      
    super(props);               
    this.state = {      
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({       
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}).cloneWithRows(props.myarray ? props.myarray : [])      
    };      
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getdata();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setState({     
       dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(props.myarray ? props.myarray : [])      
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <View>
        <Text>Employee List</Text>
        <ListView dataSource={this.props.myarray} renderRow={rowData => <Text
            >
              {rowData}
            </Text>} />
      </View>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const myarray =  _.map(state.testForm.dataSource, function(v) {
    return { ...v };
  });
      return { myarray};
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps , { getdata })(testList);
```

Comment: thx for your comment ,I tried it but got error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" . Maybe my problem is something different,I'm very very new to react so still dont know some basic stuffs I guess. By the way I can see ,my json data in mapStateToProps ; console.log(state.testForm.dataSource)

Comment: I updated to do a null/undefined check. I mentioned in my comment to do something like that if necessary based on the state of your data.